# Highcharts change serie type without change datalabels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i have a menu which changes selected serie's type.

```
    if (clickId == "dashed_line"){
        serie.update({
            type: "line",
            dashStyle: 'dash',
            zIndex: 3
        });
    }
```

It works well except label appearance, i have a general state (showlabel) for dataLabels appearance.

```
    var bakSerie = new Array();
    bakSerie["type"] = serie.type;
    bakSerie["name"] = serie.name;
    bakSerie["color"] = serie.color;
    bakSerie["data"] = serie.options.data;
    bakSerie["id"] = serie.options.id;
    bakSerie["dash"] = serie.options.dashStyle;

    serie.remove();
    if (showLabel == 1) 
        var lbl = true;
    else
        var lbl = false;

    console.log("lbl: " + lbl);

    chart.addSeries({
        type: bakSerie["type"],
        name: bakSerie["name"],
        color: bakSerie["color"],
        data: bakSerie["data"],
        id: bakSerie["id"],
        dashStyle: bakSerie["dash"],
        dataLabels: lbl
    });
```

When showlabels equals to 1, i change serie type but serie's datalabel disappears.

Comment: So general issue is when you remove and add new serie then datalabels show/hide, correct? If yes, ufnrotuantely this is default behaviour, because datalables are printed when serie is renderer. You can try to use [series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) instead of remove() addSeries() as you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable/disable `dataLabels` with your `lbl` boolean, you have to use:

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: lbl
}
```

By the way, you could replace

```
if (showLabel == 1) 
     var lbl = true;
else
     var lbl = false;
```

with

```
var lbl = (showLabel == 1);
```